# Angular HTTP POST request give me a CORS error, but the Status Code is 200 and I can see the JSON in Chrome Network tab

Tags: angular, http

I need to get data from a third part server. They gave me the URL and params (provider & token). I made a simple HTTP POST request but I don't get the JSON. I tried with an online API Client and it works. Then tried with POSTMAN and it works too. The problem is with my Angular App. I get a CORS error, but when I go to the Network Tab, the Status Code is 200 and I can see the JSON response in the Preview and Response tabs.

What could I have forgotten?

I've tried with ReqBin (online HTTP/REST/SOAP API client) and POSTMAN... both worked!

I'm serving the app in *HTTPS* localhost

*** SERVICE ***

```
  getBookings(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://myprovider.com/api/bookings/';
    const params = 'provider=999&token=c56fgfgb5443rffhu5677';
    const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    })};
    return this._http.post(url, params, options)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('Bookings loaded')),
        map((value) => value),
        catchError(this.handleError('Error = ', []))
      );
  }
```

*** COMPONENT ***

```
  getDataFromServer(): void {
    this.bookingService.getBookings().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.bookings = response;
        console.log(this.bookings);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have access to the API server. The response you are getting needs to have the following header

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Not necessarily * but your host name would suffice.

The thing is that the browsers block xhr requests that originate from different hosts than the api they are trying to access.

This is for the api protection and the application and thus its the api that should include the exception in the response header.

You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Athanasios Kataras!! I've notified to the API owner about the Header. Just a clarification: *I can see the JSON response I need in the Chrome's Network tab*... Is it because of that block that my app can't access this JSON? Thanks again!!

Comment: Exactly. The browser gets the response the same way postman and other tools do, but does not allow the javascript to access the content.

Comment: Got it. Then I will wait until they allow me to access the API server. Thanks for your quick reply @Athanasios!!!

Comment: Glad I could hello. Don't forget to accept and upvote helpful answers.